# No se ha proporcionado ninguna instancia de origen de datos para el origen de datos 'data'

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

estoy trabajando con ASP.NET, estoy creando un RDLC, ya tengo las clase con la que conecta los dataset, pero al momento de correrlo me marca esta leyenda en el navegador "No se ha proporcionado ninguna instancia de origen de datos para el origen de datos 'data'.",
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]ya tengo generado los datasets, el reporte, la base de datos.
anexo la clase C# en donde configuro. Asi esta configurado el reporte,
de igual manera agrego como tengo mis data sets, [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;



namespace V1.RDLC

{



  public partial class VistaWeb : System.Web.UI.Page


 {
    
    //Datageneral DG = null;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("../RDLC/General.rdlc");
            Datageneral DG = GetData("Select * from Reporte1CarteraGral");
            ReportDataSource data = new ReportDataSource("DG", DG.Tables[0]);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(data);
        }
        //DG = new Datageneral();
        //ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
        
    }

    private Datageneral GetData(string query)
    {
        string con1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestReportsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con1))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cm.Connection = con;
                sd.SelectCommand = cm;

                using (Datageneral Data1 = new Datageneral())
                {
                    sd.Fill(Data1, "Reporte1CarteraGral");
                    return Data1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema. Lograste resolverlo de algún modo?

Comment: No, ya no le di continuidad al proyecto, cambie de empresa y quedo otra persona a cargo